# Commenting problems when using Opera Mini to browse AU

Tags: bug, status-declined, comments

Now comment button wont work for my questions and answer to my questions . Is it a bug or am I blocked due to rude behavier?

PS:Commenting IN others questions and its answers still works

Edit1

I forgot to mention that I am using mobile version of askubuntu via opera mini

this problem is not specific to a simple question . It appears in all questions in askubuntu

After logout and back metaaskubuntu comments also disabled :(

Edit2

Full site works without any problem ,only mobile version have this issue :-)

Edit3:

```
This bug is fixed  by operateam or stackexchange team , Now no problem :)
```

Comment: commenting in meta works :o

Comment: If it is working, deleting this question is necessary

Comment: Commenting on both mine/others works fine for the mobile version on iOS 5. Opera Mini often has these issues for JS/AJAX stuff because it has to pass through their proxifying engine.

Comment: What @izx said. We do not support Opera Mini since a) hardly anyone uses it to access our sites, and b) it is pretty much unsupportable due to their architectural decisions.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a specific question you had in mind or is this global to all your main-site questions?

You should be able to comment unless:

- You're not logged in properly. Anon and new users can't comment.
- The question (or answer) you're trying to comment on is locked (none of yours appear to be)
- You've been suspended. You only have 1 rep in these cases which stops you doing things.

This is by no means an answer but try logging out and back in.